# Is there a government-mandated resource that lists the shareholders of a public company?

Tags: investing, stocks, shares

Is there a government-mandated resource that lists the shareholders of a public company, preferably if it included the quantity of shares each shareholder owns?

Would that take the form of something like eTrade's "Insider Activity" tab when viewing a particular company, except listing all public shareholders?

Comment: What country are you looking for?

Comment: I think this question can be salvaged if it asks (only) whether there is such a thing as a public register of shareholders -- as opposed to a request for a specific service providing such.

Comment: @Ganesh Sittapampalam: I added "government mandated" to "resource," and voted to reopen. Since such resources are specified by "law," they will not become "obsolete," unless the law changes. See also Chris W. Rea's comment.

Comment: Thanks, I cast the 5th reopen vote. I was probably a bit trigger-happy about closing it when it got an off-topic answer, it was marginal in its original form but seems fine now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of the public companies is available on the regulatory agencies' sites usually (for example, in the US, you can look at SEC filings). Otherwise, you can check the stock exchange listings, which show all the public companies traded on that exchange.

The shareholders, on the other hand, are normally not listed and not published. You'll have to ask the company, and it probably won't tell you (and won't even know them all as many shares are held in the "street name" of the broker).

Comment: Yeah I was specifically interested in the list of investors for companies I already know about. That's a shame, but expected.

Comment: @anxiety, in Australia you can get such information from company share registries, but you have to pay for the information. That is how certain individuals or companies get shareholder's information and send them bogus off market offers for their shares at a fraction of the current market price. They usually aim for novice mum and dad investors who don't have a clue what the real value of their shares are and who think that the offer is coming from the company they own shares in.

Comment: Unless you are trying to do something similar the information is not really that helpful. Most brokers or analyst sites will provide a list of the 10 or 20 largest shareholders for a certain companies and their share holdings. It also provides information on the activity of these big players, if they have recently bought or sold any of their shareholdings. This can be usefull in certain circumstances, as it gives you an indication of which of the big players are moving in and out of the stock.

Comment: My intention was to see some of the share traffic amongst the shareholders (who may not be the largest shareholders) at a company that recently went public. I figure if you see a trend in employee transactions it could speak towards if the investment is a good one or not.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with trying to get this data:

- The company doesn't know. The investors are insiders, employees, and regular people. But the investments are held as individual shares via the company, and brokerages. But they are also held through index funds, actively traded mutual funds, ETFs.
- There is no central repository of all this data.
- The data, even if available, would be highly perishable. Every second the data would change. Sell your shares in a mutual fund and you no longer are an investor in company X.
- Without a central repository of the data, conflation would be a big problem. You would never be able to cross reference the data between the different stores of data.

Answer (score 4):

There are several such "lists."

The one that is maintained by the company is called the shareholder registry. That is a list that the company has given to it by the brokerage firms. It is a start, but not a full list, because many individual shareholders hold their stock with say Merrill Lynch, in "street name" or anonymously.

A more useful list is the one of institutional ownership maintained by the SEC. Basically, "large" holders (of more than 5 percent of the stock) have to register their holdings with the SEC. More to the point, large holders of stocks, the Vanguards, Fidelitys, etc. over a certain size, have to file ALL their holdings of stock with the SEC. These are the people you want to contact if you want to start a proxy fight.

The most comprehensive list is held by the Depositary Trust Company. People try to get that list only in rare instances.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such list, as the other answers mention it is practically impossible to compile one.  However you can see the *institutional* investors of a public company.  MSN Money has this information available in a fair amount of details.  For example see the [Institutional Investors of GOOG](http://investing.money.msn.com/investments/institutional-ownership?symbol=GOOG)

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a stocklist if you file a lawsuit as a shareholder against the company demanding that you receive the list. It's called an inspection case. The company then has to go to Cede and/or the Depository Trust Company who then compiles the NOBO COBO list of beneficiary stockholders. SEC.gov gives you a very limited list of people who have had to file 13g or 13d or similar filings. These are large holders. To get the list of ALL stockholders you have to go through Cede.